# How to untar multiple Xtar.gzY files conatining image dataset

Tags: ubuntu, gzip, tar

I have multiple `Xtar.gzY` files that I want to see the content I've tried to combine all using:

```
cat Xtar*.gzY* > 1.tar.gz`  >>> 1.tar.gz file (100 gb)
```

then:

```
tar xvzf 1.tar.gz
```

I got this error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
printf Xtar*.gzY* | xargs tar -tvzf
```